# Two branches made changes to the same file. How to commit the changes of the file made in one branch and push to github master branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, one branch for a particular feature, and the master branch. Two branches made some changes to the same file. Now I only want to commit the changes made in the master branch and push to github, leaving the changes made in the feature branch behind. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cherry pick those changes by the unique commit

```
git-cherry-pick 'commitId'
```

Documentation found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Answer (score 0):

You can stash your changes in `feature` branch and checkout to `master` branch:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git add filename
git commit -m "..."
```

After that, you can return to `feature` branch, recover your changes stashed, and continue working from there:

```
git checkout feature
git stash apply
```

If you want to discard the changes made in that branch, you didn't need the git stash before and you can just delete that branch:

```
git branch -D feature
```